# When I boot a USB in UEFI mode, it just boots windows instead. Legacy mode works fine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, uefi, windows-10

I've been trying to get a dualboot setup of Windows (8.1 when I started, now 10) and Ubuntu for a while now.

When I install in legacy mode, I cannot get the grubloader to appear. I can look at my partition tables and see that space has been taken up by the installation, but the actual grubloader doesn't appear when I start the computer and there's no option to boot into it.

I've read that you can't really install Linux properly in legacy mode if your windows is in UEFI, and it is, but whenever I boot into UEFI mode it just boots into windows instead.

At this point you would likely recommend boot-repair, but that doesn't work, because it also wants to be ran in UEFI mode (and running it from a linux liveCD doesn't work either as boot-repair then tells me it needs to be run from its own liveCD, which, UEFI problem...)

Motherboard is an Asus A88XM-A. All the boot options are set to both legacy and UEFI currently, but I've already tested each option one by one and it doesn't appear that changing that helps.

Any ideas? I have pretty big gaps in my technological knowledge so I'm hoping this is something simple that I've overlooked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds as if the Ubuntu installation medium is not booting in EFI mode. If this assessment is incorrect, please clarify. If I'm right, then there are a number of things you can try:

- Disable BIOS/CSM/legacy support in the firmware setup utility. Those options make it difficult to control the boot mode, as described in more detail on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)
- Use your firmware's built-in boot manager to force a boot in EFI mode. Typically, you access the boot manager by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key (which key varies greatly from one system to another). If the CSM is active (and perhaps even if it's not), a USB flash drive is likely to show up as two options, one with the string "UEFI" and the other without that string. Select the "UEFI" option to boot in that mode. Note, however, that details vary greatly from one computer to another. If you disable the CSM and the USB drive doesn't show up at all, it may be missing an EFI-mode boot loader -- see the next point.
- Most people use tools like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), [Startup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), or [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create their Linux installation media. Such tools (and especially older versions of these tools) sometimes drop one boot loader or another, or create disks that particular EFIs dislike. Thus, you may need to try another tool to create your boot medium, or at least fiddle with the options provided by the tool you use. If you've got access to an existing Linux (even the Ubuntu installer booted in BIOS mode should do, although you'll need an extra USB flash drive), you can also try `dd` in Linux to copy the `.iso` file to a USB flash drive, as in `sudo dd if=imagefile.iso of=/dev/sdc` to write `imagefile.iso` to `/dev/sdc`. One or both of those options may have to be changed, of course.

Also, what symptoms are you seeing when you try to boot in EFI mode? Do you see an error message? Do you see a GRUB menu with options for what to do? How far the boot progresses could reveal a lot about what's going on. (My preceding suggestions assume that you can't get even as far as a GRUB boot menu.) If you get further than this, then the problem could be something to do with video or other drivers, which might be corrected by passing particular options to the kernel using GRUB.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the response. I was out watching the new DBZ movie (which was fantastic), so sorry for the late reply. Currently all that happens when I boot into EFI mode is that it goes right into the windows loading screen with the circle. I used YUMI to make the installation media, but I'll look into that and see how it works. But I'm already using the method you suggested for booting into EFI mode :/ The EFI mode just boots windows like I said, while the legacy option works but I guess it's hard to install linux in legacy while you already have windows in EFI.